# Fortran about creating function

Tags: function, fortran

When I compile the program below, I have an error as

> Return type mismatch of function 'j17' (unknown/real(4))"

```
program Jfun

    implicit none
    real :: R = 1.5, X1 = 2.5, X3 = 4.8, EPS1 = 0.5
    write(*,*) J17(R,X1,X3,EPS1)

end program Jfun

real function J17(R,X1,X3,EPS1)

    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: R,X1,X3,EPS1
    J17 = -((R+X1-EPS1)*(X3**2-R**2)+(X3**2)*R)/(R**3)/((R+X1-EPS1)**2)

end function J17
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gfortran emits a second error that is more helpful than the one you've posted:

```
jfun.f90:5:14:

     write(*,*) J17(R,X1,X3,EPS1)
              1
Error: Function ‘j17’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Within your main program you haven't provided a type for `j17` and because implicit typing is disabled (a good thing), the compiler cannot determine a type for it.  The error you posted is a consequence of this one that `unknown` (in your main program) and `real` (in your function) are not matching types.

To fix this, make your main program aware of the type of j17.  You can do this by simply declaring it in your main program

```
real :: j17
```

This will set the type of the external function reference to `real` and this will compile.  This is not ideal however, as there is no checking of function arguments.  For that, an explicit interface is helpful.  You can write an explicit interface by hand, but it is much easier to let the compiler generate it for you.

One method is to make `j17` an internal function:

```
program Jfun

  implicit none
  real :: R = 1.5, X1 = 2.5, X3 = 4.8, EPS1 = 0.5
  write(*,*) J17(R,X1,X3,EPS1)

contains

  real function J17(R,X1,X3,EPS1)

    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: R,X1,X3,EPS1
    J17 = -((R+X1-EPS1)*(X3**2-R**2)+(X3**2)*R)/(R**3)/((R+X1-EPS1)**2)

  end function J17
end program Jfun
```

and another method is to put j17 into a module:

```
module jfunc
contains

  real function J17(R,X1,X3,EPS1)

    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: R,X1,X3,EPS1
    J17 = -((R+X1-EPS1)*(X3**2-R**2)+(X3**2)*R)/(R**3)/((R+X1-EPS1)**2)

  end function J17
end module jfunc

program Jfun
  use jfunc
  implicit none
  real :: R = 1.5, X1 = 2.5, X3 = 4.8, EPS1 = 0.5
  write(*,*) J17(R,X1,X3,EPS1)

end program Jfun
```

Both of these methods provide the compiler with information about the function `j17`'s return type and dummy arguments.  This lets the compiler do type,kind,rank checks and is also mandatory if you want to take advantage of certain language features like returning arrays or passing certain kinds of arguments.